# Javascript removing millisecond in DateTime [YYYY/MM/DD/ HH:MM:SS:MMM]

Tags: javascript

Hi is there any simple method to remove the millisecond in my datetime?

my current timestamp have the following format:

2016-03-04 14:22:33:123

I want to remove the millisecond. any advise? thanks

Comment: How do you generate it?

Comment: try: `var res = dateString.substr(0, 19);`

Comment: Do you want to remove milliseconds from a Date object (setting them to 0)? Or do you want to print a date without milliseconds?

Answer (score 0):

Use [moment.js](https://momentjs.com/) library.

install,
npm install moment --save

then,
moment(2016-03-04 14:22:33:123).format('YYYY MM DD, h:mm:ss');

Comment: It is possible to do it via native `Date` object. No need to use a library for such small thing. `myDate.setMilliseconds(0)`